# Android Stopping Runnable onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-volley, handler, runnable

I have a runnable on an interval using a handler, which controls my volley requests:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

     //Volley request...
     AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(volleyreq);

     handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
   }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

I need my requests to stop when my users press the back button and confirm the dialog. This stops my location updates, "checks" the user out, and switches to the `CheckinActivity`. Can I somehow insert the `removeCallbacks()` method at this point or where exactly would it go?

`onBackPressed()`:

```
//Checking Out With Back Button
public void onBackPressed() {

  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Checking Out!");
  alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to check out?");
  alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Inserting here crashes app after pressing back button
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

        //Disconnects from location updates...
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        //Fires a volley POST request...
        checkout();

        Intent intent=new Intent(OrderListActivity.this,CheckinActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        OrderListActivity.this.finish();

      }
  });

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
      }
  });

  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
  alertDialog.show();

}
```

I've tried firing it from various places but it always crashes my app and give me a null pointer exception.

Crash Log:

```
08-20 19:41:08.540 2815-2815/com.myapp.workingprojectlocal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.myapp.workingprojectlocal, PID: 2815
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.myapp.workingprojectlocal.OrderListActivity$12.onClick(OrderListActivity.java:394)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please provide crash log and ping me.

Comment: stopping the location updates would be a good idea in onPause method

Comment: I changed it to onPause and it works! Good to know it works in various places :)

Comment: Hmmm, so you only want to stop the location updates?

Comment: No, the runnable. I can stop location updates without a problem.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference` means your handler instance is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this to work. The NPE was due to not initializing the handler class wide. After I fixed that the runnable would still not stop with `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);` What seems to be working is:

`handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`.

Answer (score 0):

It means your handler is `NULL`. Do like this:

```
if (handler !=null && runnable !=null)
   handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

It should fix your problem.

Comment: No go. Runnable still runs.

Comment: @glokul Your Logs indicates that the handler instance is null.

Comment: I see that, but how can I fix that? It's a real puzzler to me.

Comment: @glokul Somewhere it goes 'Null'. I see your code but there isn't anything wrong. Update your question with your full activity codes, Please.